# How can I make Bootstrap alert appear on top of other elements?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5, alert

I have an input box that if the value is not valid on button click should send out a bootstrap alert. I want the alert to appear on top of the input box.

Right now, it is showing below the input box. Is there a way to make it appear in the middle of the page **on top of the text box**?

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("mybtn");
btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("show-alert").classList.remove("d-none")
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" id="record">
    <div class="input-group mb-3 input-group-lg w-50">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rec-id" placeholder="Enter ID">
      <button class="btn btn-success" id="mybtn" type="button">Enter</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center d-none" id="show-alert">
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show row">
      <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert"></button>
      <strong>Danger!</strong> Button was clicked
    </div>
  </div>
```

Also on closing the alert box, is there a way to add the `d-none` class back?

Comment: Side note, the way you're using the alert isn't really correct. It will only display once.

Comment: @j08691 how do I fix that? I want the alert to show up everytime the button is clicked.

Comment: Don't you want to check the input's value and only display the alert if it's invalid? The way it is now, it will show up regardless

Comment: @j08691 I have the logic in place to check the validity of the text box value

Comment: Don't you want to check the input's value and only display the alert if it's invalid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you want a [vertically centered modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/modal/#vertically-centered). It would probably give you a better, more accessible UX.

If you do want an alert, Bootstrap provides [methods](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/alerts/#live-example) for showing them. Always try to work *with* a library, not alongside it, to reduce effort. That's also how you'd make it reusable.

To answer the question as asked, use [positioning classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/position/#center-elements). I used `position-fixed` to set the alert with respect to the viewport instead of a parent element, and centering is done with `top-50 start-50 translate-middle`.

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("mybtn");
btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("show-alert").classList.remove("d-none")
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" id="record">
  <div class="input-group mb-3 input-group-lg w-50">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rec-id" placeholder="Enter ID">
    <button class="btn btn-success" id="mybtn" type="button">Enter</button>
  </div>
</div>

<p>Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. </p>

<p>Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. </p>

<p>Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. </p>

<p>Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. </p>

<p>Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. Other content. </p>

<div class="position-fixed top-50 start-50 translate-middle d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center d-none" id="show-alert">
  <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show row">
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert"></button>
    <strong>Danger!</strong> Button was clicked
  </div>
</div>
```